# How to get gridPanel cell value? ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a gridPanel with `ColumnModel`. One of this columns is `ActionColumn` with buttons. And i want by click a button get a cell value from cell in same row with this button? How to do this?

My ActionColumn

```
{
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        width: 50,
        items: [{
               icon   : url_servlet+'externals/gxp/src/theme/img/pencil.png', 
            tooltip: 'Редактировать участок',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            alert("DAMACIA!!!!");
           }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but i think that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447401/how-to-read-and-set-a-value-of-a-specific-cell-in-an-extjs-grid) will help.

Agnese

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have all you need in handler params

```
handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            var row = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
            console.log(row);
           }
```

The code above will give you the row, so you just need to select desired cell.

If you enforce selection before clicking actioncolumn you can also use code below. But be aware by default clicking on actioncolumn doesn't fire selection, so while clicking actioncolumn an entirely different row can be selected or even no column can be selected at all.

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()
```

Comment: I solved it like in your example. But i think exist more optimal option to do this.